# Save Cookie in Transaction ID and use in Shopify thank you page

Tags: javascript, cookies, shopify, session-cookies

I'm looking for ways to save session cookie into transaction_id from the landing URL and use this transaction_id in the conversion pixel within thank you page.

Landing URL Eg. https://advertiser.myshopify.com/?utm_source=publisher&**transaction_id=102d76ce80070f3f8aa28637124a21**

Conversion Pixel in Additional Script Eg.

```html
<img src="https://publisher.com/aff_l?offer_id=1234&currency={{ shop.currency }}&amount={{ line_item.final_line_price | money_without_currency | remove: ',' }}&adv_sub={{ order.order_number }}&adv_sub2={{ customer.orders_count }}&adv_sub3={{ line_item.title }}&adv_sub4={{ line_item.sku }}&adv_sub5={{ line_item.vendor }}&transaction_id={{ transaction_id }}" width="1" height="1" style="position:fixed; left:-100px" />
```

I'm using a javascript at landing page to save the transaction id as below:

```js
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var source = url.searchParams.get("utm_source");
var transaction = url.searchParams.get("transaction_id");
if (source == "publisher") {
  localStorage.setItem('utm_source', source);
  localStorage.setItem('transaction_id', transaction);
}
```

However, the result of my conversion pixel at thank you page are still missing the transaction_id value

```html
<img src="https://publisher.com/aff_l?offer_id=1234&amp;currency=MYR&amp;amount=50.00&amp;adv_sub=1180&amp;adv_sub2=160&amp;adv_sub3=Nike Shirt&amp;adv_sub4=SKU0001&amp;adv_sub5=Nike&amp;transaction_id=" width="1" height="1" style="position:fixed; left:-100px">
```

Any kind soul out there able to enlighten this lost child here ?

Appreciate your time and thanks!

Comment: Once you over thank you page, you can check and run JS code from the additional scripts section from Shopify backend settings, but I am not 100% the data saved over the landing page is still available on this page due to Shopify safety policies.

Comment: I can find my transaction_id with console.log(transaction_id) at thank you page, but how should I parse this value into the conversion pixel so that {{ transaction_id }} will capture this

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the same element using Javascript and append it to the header of the page. but I am not sure how it read or work by 3rd party and sends the data.
you can try and we hope it works for you.

```
var src = 'https://publisher.com/aff_l?offer_id=1234&amp;currency=MYR&amp;amount=50.00&amp;adv_sub=1180&amp;adv_sub2=160&amp;adv_sub3=Nike Shirt&amp;adv_sub4=SKU0001&amp;adv_sub5=Nike&amp;transaction_id='+localStorage.getItem("transaction_id");
var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = src;
    img.width = '1';
    img.height = '1';
    img.style.position = 'fixed';
    img.style.left = '-100px';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(img);
```